# How to parametrize list name in jstl?

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl

I need to do three very similar blocks of code, so instead of copy&paste almost the same code, I separated it to different file and now it's parametrized during `<s:include>`. I have only one problem - in the block, I operate over a list and part of it's name is one of the parameters. While it's not a problem in iterators (`list="request.${param.name}List"`), I can't obtain list size. I need to do something like this:

`${param.name}` - is the parametrized part
`${fn:length(request.___List)}` - size of the list

instead of `___` there should go the parametrized name, but I don't know how to put it in the way that it works.

Comment: ${fn:length(pageContext.request.param.listname)} should give you the size of the list where the name of the list is listname.

Comment: no, `param.name` is only a part of list name, like for `param.name=dogs` the list to calculate length of would be `dogsList`

Comment: Use the map and put all lists there, then reference it by key as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with passing the list size as another argument, just like in C-style array operation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable for your list name and then use brace notation (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

```
<c:set var="myList" value="${param.name}List"/>
${fn:length(request[myList])}
```